# show and hide with delays on a loop but no animation

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

I have a jsfiddle for this

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x6Kpv/3/)

The problem is, I am trying to create a script that ones a button is clicked flashes an image (car lights) on and off for a period of time.  It works fine, but in IE8 since the lights are png the animation for it is causing a black background and border as it blinks on and off.  So I trying to duplicate the same thing, but without using animation.

In my jsfiddle, the first function for the first click div represents what i am trying to do without animation, but it is not repeating.  The code:

```
$('.oneD').click(function(){
  for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {
    $('.oneP').show();
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.oneP').hide();
    }, 1000);       
  }
});
```

The 2nd function is the one I already created that does work, but it has the animation:

```
$('.twoD').click(function(){
for (var i = 0; i <= 9; i++) {              
    $(".twoP").fadeIn(1000, function () {
        $(".twoP").hide();
    });
}   
});
```

Keep in mind that the jsfiddle is just a simple mock not using images.  I am just looking for the functionality in which i can incorporate this.  I appreciate your time in helping me with this.

Answer (score 1):

instead of `setTimeout()` use `setInterval()` and `clearInterval()` like this:

```
$('.oneD').click(function(){
    $('.oneP').show();
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        $('.oneP').hide();
    }, 1000);
    //*after a number of time or loop
    interval.clearInterval();
});
```

`setInterval()` "Loop" throught the function it is given every number of millisecond you pass it. and `clearInterval()` stop the "Loop".

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it like this :

```
$('.oneD, .twoD').on('click', function(){
  for (var i=0; i<9; i++)
      $('.'+this.className.replace('D', 'P')).delay(1000).show(0)
                                             .delay(1000).hide(0);
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/x6Kpv/5/)

This uses a selector for both elements and the same event handler, then swaps out the D for a P in the showing and hiding.

As for using `delay()` and making this work, `hide()` and `show()` will work just as the animated jQuery methods if a value for the duration is passed, even if that value is zero.

Comment: The current jquery docs for delay() specifically mention that hide() and show() bypass the animation fx queue if the duration is 0. Set it to 1 instead. Also, consider refactoring the paragraph classname outside of the loop, rather than recalculating the same value 9 times. :)

Comment: @Palpatim - I actually always set the duration to `1` for that reason, but I just tried `0` for fun, and it works just fine, and if the fx queue was bypassed `delay()` wouldn't work, so that's not really an issue. As for calculating the `className`, it's already cached in `this`, so using a second variable would make no significant difference in any modern browser.

Comment: And the [docs for delay()](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) specifically says "this will not delay the ***no-arguments forms*** of `.show()` or `.hide()` which do not use the effects queue", in other words, just passing an argument is enough, nowhere does it say a zero is not good enough ?

Comment: Sorry, I mis-wrote: the docs for show() and hide() mention the no-args and zero forms not being delayed: "Note that .hide() is fired immediately and will override the animation queue if no duration or a duration of 0 is specified." Delay specifically mentions the no-arguments form, but zero is not mentioned. The proof is in the pudding, though: $('foo').delay(1000).hide(0) executes with a delay as expected. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/HxFpr/

```
    var i;

    $('.twoD').click(function(){
    i = 0;
    loopFlash();  
    });

   function loopFlash(){
       if(i < 10){  // flash 5 times (1 on 1 off = 2 cycles)
        $('.twoP').toggle();   
       var flashing = setTimeout(loopFlash,500);
       }    

   i++;
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Yet another solution for you.

- No Animation - with single interval
- With animation - pure jQuery

http://jsfiddle.net/x6Kpv/6/

```
var noAnimationHandler = function() {    
    setInterval(function() {   
        var $el = $('.oneP');
        $el[$el.is(":visible") ? "hide" : "show"]();
    }, 800);
};

var animationHanddler = function() {
    $('.twoP').fadeIn(300, function() {
        $(this).delay(150).fadeOut(300, animationHanddler);
    });
}

$('.oneD').click(noAnimationHandler);
$('.twoD').click(animationHanddler);
```

Thanks